# Huawei Ideos - LogCat not responding

Tags: android-logcat

I have a Huawei Ideos X3, which is supposedly properly connected through usb (driver was installed, and no yellow exclamation mark on device manager). I can install and run my Apps through Eclipse, however i don't get any response on LogCat. So i cannot have any feedback for debugging... Anyone has a clue..? Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To enable logging on Huawei Blaze (U8510) (rebadged Ideos X3):

- dial *#*#2846579#*#*
- select 'ProjectMenu'
- select 'Background Setting'
- select 'Log Setting'
- select 'Log Switch'
- enable 'LOG on'
- Select 'Log level setting'
- enable 'DEBUG'
- Press the 'Back' key
- select 'Dump and Log'
- enable 'Open Dump and Log'
- Press 'Back' key 5 times to return to home screen.
- Reboot the phone.
- LogCat should now work.

Comment: @Keith...thanks a lot . I was facing this problem from long time. and search over the Google. now I my device shows logcat .

Comment: This also works on Huawei Y300 (I've just tested it)

Comment: Thank you so much, I can finally debug normally. (Y300)

Comment: Time saving answer!

Comment: Works on Mate 10 Lite! 
But LOG Settings is little different in Huawei Mate 10 Lite. 
You need to enable **AP Log** to get it working.