# Android logcat logging only info level on real device. Cannot get debug messages, not even unhandled exceptions

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-hardware

I am developing for android for some time, and so far I didnt have any problem with logcat. Until now, i have new phone for development, Huawei Y300 (Y300-0100) and in logcat there is no messages from DEBUG level. This is problem, because I don't get Exceptions stack trace prints. I have to use emulator for that, you understand that it is annoying..

So far i figured out this:

from:

```
    Log.v("TEST VERBOSE", "verbose level");
    Log.d("TEST DEBUG", "debug level");
    Log.i("TEST INFO", "info level");
    Log.w("TEST WARN", "warn level");
    Log.e("TEST ERROR", "error level");
    Log.wtf("TEXT WTF", "?? level");
```

Only this was printed:

```
    INFO/TEST INFO(21224): info level
    WARN/TEST WARN(21224): warn level
    ERROR/TEST ERROR(21224): error level
```

On emulator, ofcourse all of them are printed.
And on previous phones there was no problem(Huawei G300 and ZTE Blade).

I have been searching for solution for sometime, and did not find any.

Comment: Is there a Developer Options on that phone? Any particular settings you have to enable besides the common on in stock Android build?

Comment: @fasteque In developer options is nothing more then usual, and I tried  some of them turn off/on. Nothing helped.

Comment: if from command line (platform-tools dir for example), you try adb kill-server, adb devices (so you check you device is the only one connected) and then adb logcat? Of course launch your application :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem on Samsung tab 2...how to enable this on samsung tab 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778896/huawei-ideos-logcat-not-responding). I have the same phone and I was experiencing the same problems until I tryied that.