# Huawei Y300-0100 debugging issue

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I am experiencing problems in order to see in Logcat the information related with the debug of my applications.
I never had that problem before, but when I recently purchased a Huawei Y300-0100 for developing I faced that issue. This problem doesn't appear using other devices.

A snapshot of the LogCat:

```
11-08 01:32:24.960: E/Trace(24713): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 01:04:53.290: W/dalvikvm(23882): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
11-08 01:04:55.570: I/Adreno200-EGL(23882): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
11-08 01:04:55.570: I/Adreno200-EGL(23882): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
11-08 01:04:55.570: I/Adreno200-EGL(23882): Local Branch: 
11-08 01:04:55.570: I/Adreno200-EGL(23882): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
11-08 01:04:55.570: I/Adreno200-EGL(23882): Local Patches: NONE
```

I tryied to find a solution but I have not been able to figure out what's wrong and how can I fix that.

Anybody has this smartphone and is not having issues? I would appretiate any comment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after a long search on the web I finally encountered [that answer][1]: [Huawei Ideos - LogCat not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778896/huawei-ideos-logcat-not-responding) . Following the same instruction now I can see the debug messages like:

```
Log.d("hello","that's a probe")
```

On logcat, the "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)" has not disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the NDK library .so files in the application,I confront the same problem,I solve this problem just by fix the name of the library,Maybe that your application could not find the .so libarary.Hope it give some ideas.