# Empty logcat output with android studio and a android 2.3.5 device

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I tried to restart everything. Logcat, Android Studio, Macbook, Smartphone but the log including crashlog keeps empty [image: Empty Logcat]

Comment: I found the solution here in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545628/690918

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved The same Problem With fully **uninstall** my **JDK v7 (jdk and jre)** and downloading new **JDK v8** from Oracle Site and installing them on my Windows 8.1 System (it supposed to do the trick in mac I think).
remember after that you should restart your Android Studio and Go to:
**File > Default Settings > Default Project Structure** 
and update your JDK path.