# Missing stacktrace in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I am creating an app and I seem to be having a problem with logcat. The IDE is Android Studio and I have selected the right device and application. I also set the filter to "No Filters" and tried showing only from selected application. The log level is set to verbose.

Whenever my app crashes I only get this error in logcat: `thread exiting with uncaught exception`. To my understanding there should be a stacktrace as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: `Attache debugger to android process and analyze logcat.`

Comment: When I run the app data is logged to logcat, but stacktraces are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to a hidden menu in my Huawei Y300 to enable logging.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778896/huawei-ideos-logcat-not-responding) helped me.